# get some substring inside a large string with symbols

Tags: c#, string

```
   string s =  "201031070!0+583#583#$201031070!10000+483#583#"
```

How can I get easily the last numerical value before the last `#`? In the above case `583`.

I only tried in SQL something like this:

```
SUBSTRING(s,CHARINDEX('#',s)+1, CHARINDEX('#',s,CHARINDEX('#',s)+1) -CHARINDEX('#',s)-1)
```

but I have problems trying to achieve this  in c#

Comment: What have you tried so far? What problem are you facing?

Comment: Probably not the more efficient but `string s =  "201031070!0+583#583#$201031070!10000+483#583#".Trim('#').Split('#').Last();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Regex:

```
var substring = Regex.Match(s, @"\d+(?=#$)").Value;
```

This matches one or more digits, followed by a `#` symbol at the end of the string:

`\d+`: one or more digits.

`(?=#$)`: followed by a `#` (not included in the result).

Comment: Would it matter if the string ends in some '$' chars? something like this: string s = "201031070!0+583#583#$201031070!10000+483#583#$$"

Comment: @Akhtubir Yes, the pattern would no longer work for that string. You would need to change the lookahead part from `(?=#$)` to `(?=#\$*$)`, the pertinent part being `\$*`, which would allow zero or more `$` characters to appear at the end of the string. If you want to update your question I'll update my answer.

Comment: And if I don't know the exact number of those '$' from the end of the string?

Comment: @Akhtubir It doesn't matter because it will work with any number of `$` characters. `*` means match zero or more.